# Google sheets API gives Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api, fetch-api

I am trying to connect a very basic web, only HTML/CSS/JS, with google sheets. When I submit the form to upload the data to the sheet I get:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch
> resource.

​I have been reading all over that this is because of CORS but I cannot figure out how to solve it. The code that I have is very simple, in the google script:

```
function doPost(e){
  let jsonResponse;

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName('web')
  const headers = ws.getRange(1, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  const body = e.postData.contents;
  const bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body);

  jsonResponse = ws.appendRow([bodyJSON.name, bodyJSON.email])    
  return sendJSON_(jsonResponse) 
}

function sendJSON_(jsonResponse) {
  return  ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(jsonResponse)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

I have reduced the code of my HTML to the minimum and its:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id='form' class="form">
    <form id="customerForm">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name">
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Send</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        function afterSubmit(e){
        url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/........../exec'
        var name = document.getElementById('name')
        var email = document.getElementById('email')
        var info = {
            name: name.value,
            email: email.value
        };
        console.log(info);

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            redirect: 'follow',
            body: JSON.stringify(info)
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
          }

        document.getElementById('customerForm').addEventListener('submit', afterSubmit);

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have also checked that when I publish the google sheets script as web app I have the options correctly set to:
execute the app as: me (email@gmail.com)
who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous

The way I get the error in console is simply opening the HTML file with the browser, fill data and press send.

Comment: I am a bit confused because you mention that this is a web app, which would suggest that its a apps script project, yet you say you have a "local" version and a js file, where is this "local"? Can you clarify how you set this project up?

Comment: @iansedano I have edited to make it more clear. When I say "web app" is the option of publishing as web app the Google sheets script. The JS file corresponds to the web page that I want to connect with the Google sheets script

Comment: I'm sorry but I still am finding it hard to understand how exactly you have it set up. Where is this remote "web page"? What is it exactly? A remote server? Could it be due to that remote server having certain restrictions in relation to CORS? Please refer to [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @iansedano I have reduced the code to the minimum I can, I hope now it is understandable

Comment: If you are indeed getting a CORS error (the error you shared _might_ be CORS, but I think you didn't share a full error) then there is likely not much you can do to fix this. Google is not going to let 3rd parties directly access their endpoints.

Comment: @Evert that is the error it appears in the console when inspecting code, it does not say anything else

Comment: try to `.catch()` and log your promise chains. Might yield more information. Also look at the network tab.

Comment: Can I ask you about "web" tab in your current Spreadsheet? If you can do, could you please show it as an image?

Comment: @Evert using catch did not show anything useful

Comment: @tanaike it is just an empty page with "name" and 'email' in the A1, B1

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that your issue had been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modified Apps Script

```js
function doPost(e){
  let jsonResponse;

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName('web')
  const headers = ws.getRange(1, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  const body = e.postData.contents;
  const bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body);

  jsonResponse = {"name": bodyJSON.name, "email": bodyJSON.email} // MODIFIED
  ws.appendRow([jsonResponse.name, jsonResponse.email]) // MODIFIED
}
```

- I believe your main problem was with this line

  ```
  jsonResponse = ws.appendRow([bodyJSON.name, bodyJSON.email])
  ```

  If you see the [`appendRow` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) it says the return type is a `Sheet`. So in theory, without my modification, the next line should have returned an error. What do the executions in your Apps Script dashboard say? That said, it might have still been able to update the sheet.

  With this modified, your HTML successfully updated the script even though it threw a bunch of errors in the browser console.
- You don't need to explicitly return anything either for it to function, which is why I omitted it here.

#### Modified HTML

```js
function afterSubmit(e) {
  url =
    "https://script.google.com/macros/s/<SCRIPT_ID>/exec";
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var email = document.getElementById("email");
  var info = {
    name: name.value,
    email: email.value,
  };
  console.log(info);

  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    cache: "no-cache",
    mode: "no-cors", // to prevent CORS errors
    redirect: "follow",
    body: JSON.stringify(info),
  })
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  e.preventDefault(); // to prevent form from reloading page
}

document.getElementById("customerForm").addEventListener("submit", afterSubmit);
```

- Only thing added here was the `mode: "no-cors"`.
- The `e.preventDefault()` at the end supressed a "Failed to Fetch" error I was getting because the form submit automatically reloaded the page. It seems that since the page reload happened before a response could come back it would just say "failed" although it was successful in updating the script.
- The returned object is actually blank because of the no-cors argument, see [response type](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#response_types).

If you wanted a more meaningful response, @Tanaike has in previous posts suggested something using async, like this:

```js
const fetchData = async (url, info) => {
  var json;
  try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(info),
      });
      if (response != "") json = await response.json();
      console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(json));
  } catch (e) {
      console.log('Errors:', e.message)
  }
  return json;
}

async function main() {
    const res = await fetchData(url, info);
    console.log(res);
}

main()
```

Which would also require adding this to the Apps Script side:

```js
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

#### References

- [Response types](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#response_types)
- [`appendRow` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)